# checking existing information in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP file to insert user info to the database if the info is already in the database, it will says `"user is already exists"`.There are 3 fields in my form "full name","email" and "phone".For example these info already in the database is "myName","myEmail@yahoo.com","0123456789".if user types exactly these letters it will show up the message "user is already exists".However if they type the phone number like (083)0123456789 it will insert into the database. How to fix this error?
Here are the files
register.php

```
<h1>register form</h1>
<?php
$labels=array("full_name"=>"Full Name",
                "email"=>"Email",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
echo "<form action='check_register.php' method='POST'>";
foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
{
    echo "$value <input type='text' name='$key'/><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

check_register.php

```
<?php
$labels=array("full_name"=>"Full Name",
                "email"=>"Email",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value)
{
    if(empty($value))
    {
        $empty_value[]=$key;
    }
    elseif($key=="full_name")
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z '-]{2,50}$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
    elseif($key=="email")
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}+(@)[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}(\.com)$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
    elseif($key=="phone")
    {   
        if(!preg_match("/^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
}

if(@sizeof($empty_value)>0 or @sizeof($invalid_value)>0)
{
    if(@sizeof($empty_value)>0)
    {
        echo "input ";
        foreach($empty_value as $key) //loop empty value
        {
            echo " $labels[$key] ";
        }
    }
    if(@sizeof($invalid_value)>0)
    {
        echo "<br/>invalid data ";
        foreach($invalid_value as $key) //loop invalid_value
        {
            echo " $labels[$key]    ";
        }
    }
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
    foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
    {
        echo "$value <input type='text' name='$key'/><br/>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
else
    {
        $user='root';
        $host='localhost';
        $password='root';
        $dbname='pet';
        $connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");
        foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
        {
            $good_data[$key]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$key]));
            $good_data[$key]=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$good_data[$key]);
        }
        $check_exist="SELECT ";
        foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
        {
            $check_exist.=$key.",";
        }
        $check_exist=preg_replace("/phone,/","phone",$check_exist);
        $check_exist.=" FROM register WHERE ";
        $arrayValue=array();
        foreach($good_data as $key =>$value)
        {
            $arrayValue[]=$key."="."'$value'";
        }

        $check_exist.=join(" AND ",$arrayValue);
        $query=$check_exist;
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
        {
            echo "user already exist !";
            echo $check_exist;
            exit(); 
        }

        echo $check_exist;
        else
        {
        foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
            {
                $good_data[$key]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$key]));
                    if($key=="phone")
                    {
                        $good_data[$key]=preg_replace("/(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)/","",$good_data[$key]);

                    }
                $good_data[$key]=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$good_data[$key]);
            }
            $query="INSERT INTO register ("; 
            foreach($good_data as $key =>$value)
            {
                $query.="$key,"; 
            }
            $query.= ") VALUES (";      
            $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query);
            foreach($good_data as $key =>$value)   
            {
                $query.="'$value',";
            }
            $query.=")";
            $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query);
            $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die ("can't execute query.".mysqli_error($connect));
            echo "$query";
            echo "<h4>member inserted $query </h4>";        
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Try to check with `substr_count`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 1):

You should first filter the fields, NOT require the user to use an exact format, by first using a reference to the value:
`foreach($_POST as $key => & $value) {`

then under the phone entry, filter out non-numbers, then change how you test the data to something like:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $value);
if (strlen($value) != 10) {
  $invalid_value[]=$key;
}
```

If you need to allow longer than 10 character phone numbers, set a range for the test, but then you will have difficulty matching phone numbers as you mentioned before. Anybody putting in 123-456-7890 and then someone else doing 123-456-78901 - these will appear as different numbers because you allow different lengths.